# Swift does not update view constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview, constraints

I have a `UIWebView`. I'm using this code:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    self.webView.frame.size.height = 1

    self.cardBoxNameTopConstraint.constant = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero).height

    self.webView.frame.size.height = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero).height
    self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero).height
    self.contentView.frame.size.height = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero).height

    for v in self.contentView.subviews {
        v.setNeedsDisplay()
        v.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

This code is meant to get content size then apply it and resize my view, but the first time I load the view it resizes my `UIWebView`, and the `UITableViewCell` is not scrollable. When I use `UISegmentControl` to go to another screen and come back to the screen with my `UIWebView`, it resizes itself and the `UITableViewCell` is now resizable.

How can I update my view without switching between screens? I'm using `setNeedsDisplay` and `v.layoutIfNeeded` but it does not help.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can call `contentView.setNeedsDisplay()` and `contentView.layoutIfNeed()` with looping through the subviews.  Both those calls will recursively go through the subviews.

Comment: I agree with dmorrow. The problem is you're calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on the wrong view. It needs to be the superview of everything that needs laying out.